# Create class instances from an array of metatypes

Tags: swift, polymorphism, protocols, metatype

Let's suppose I do have a protocol `TestProtocol` and classes `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` conforming to `TestProtocol`:

```
protocol TestProtocol: AnyObject { }
class TestClass1: TestProtocol { }
class TestClass2: TestProtocol { }
```

Suppose further that I do have a metatype array defined like

```
var testArray: [TestProtocol.Type] = [TestClass1.self, TestClass2.self]
```

How can I create instance objects of `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` based on the entries of `testArray`?

p.s.: This should be done without creating a switch construct that checks agains `TestClass1.self` and `TestClass2.self` like

```
var instanceArray: [TestProtocol] = []
for element in testArray {
    if element == TestClass1.self {
        instanceArray.append(TestClass1())
    } else if element == TestClass2.self {
        instanceArray.append(TestClass2())
    }
}
```

I looked into generics, but did not find a suitable solution, because the metatypes are stored in an array of type `[TestProtocol.Type]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
protocol TestProtocol: AnyObject {
    init()
}

final class TestClass1: TestProtocol { }
final class TestClass2: TestProtocol { }

var testArray: [TestProtocol.Type] = [TestClass1.self, TestClass2.self]

for testType in testArray {
    let testInstance = testType.init()
}
```

The `final classes` could be `structs` as well (but you need to remove the `AnyObject` constraint)

Can you let me know if it compiles for you? If not, you need to update your toolchain.

Comment: Why should they be structs?

Comment: @Sander I said ‘could’ be structs, not should :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think that calling init() on a metatype would be possible. I probably would not have looked there any time soon.

Comment: And yes, it compiles. Just realized I did not state that explicitly in my previous comment.